# List button that calls a VF page, how to get it to work in lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

currently on the account ojbect i have a related object that has a list button

```
/apex/New_Service_VF?pId={!Account.Id}
```

that runs a VF page.

Now i'm thinking of making a quick action that initialized the VF page, and somehow pass the record id....BUT the it would be a massive rewrite as the object controller is not a standard controller... and the VF page has it's own controller.

So is it possible to create a lightning component that simply passes a record Id to a VF page and starts a VF page?

would this work?

```
    <aura:component controller="New_Service" implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
      <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.newService}"/>
</aura:component>
```

js controller

```
({
    newService : function(component, event, helper) {
            var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
            var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");


                urlEvent.setParams({
          "url": 'https://xxxxxxxx--XXXXXXXX.cs41.my.salesforce.com/apex/New_Service_VF?id=' + recordId, 

        });
        urlEvent.fire();
    }
})
```

This gets me the following error

Read timed out 
An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has been notified.

When i just use

/apex/New_Service?id=' + recordId,

i get the null page error.

All i'm trying to do is fire a VF page and pass the account record ID to it...that's it no more no less. I would use a quick action to fire the VF page (i'm using a quick action to fire this), but that would take a major rewrite of apex code.

solved: I'm a silly and the sandbox has custom setting issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice would be to use the [`lightning:navigation`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation) helper library component.  See the Page Reference examples [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation.htm), specifically the "Navigate to a Web Page".

If you're VF page is a custom tab, then you can use the Navigation Item Page Type `standard__navItemPage` as referenced [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm) (with an example on how to use it), or just use the `standard_webPage` page type for a regular VF page

Comment: So i updated my question i'm wondering if the issue is the URL, because i'm getting the null error in sfdc when it redirects.

Comment: Not sure what's giving the null error.  For what it's worth, `force:navigateToURL` is an older component event and Salesforce suggests to use `lightning:navigation` moving forward :-)  That's what they say in the official [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToURL/documentation) and you can use `standard__webPage` page type for navigating to the VF page

Comment: Miler thank you, just found it. the VF page calls on it's controller which calls on a toolingquery class we have which uses custom settings that werent changed from our production org to this sandbox lolol

Comment: Parity between your sandbox and production, happens all the time!